# Apache DefaultHttpClient: How to set max. total connection and default max. connections per route

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using a singleton `DefaultHttpClient` to make around a dozen or more parallel HTTP requests per second. I wonder how to set the values **x (max total connections)** and **y (default max connections per route)** for the 'PoolingClientConnectionManager' in the code below in a smart way.
I'd expect the `PoolingClientConnectionManager` to help me in order that I do not have to change those values if there are load peaks or if load is much lower than usual. What can I do? Or do I have to set the values to something that will always be *bigger than what I actually need*?

```
...
PoolingClientConnectionManager poolingClientConnectionManager =
    new PoolingClientConnectionManager(sr, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
poolingClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(x);
poolingClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(y);
return new DefaultHttpClient(poolingClientConnectionManager, new BasicHttpParams());
```

Edit: is it a good idea to say `poolingClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Comment: You should have an idea of what your peak load is going to be and adjust the max number accordingly. Keep in mind that just because you set an arbitrarily large max is no guarantee that the underlying client will be able to withstand very high concurrent load. The connection manager cannot do *all* your work for you.

Comment: So tomorrow I will deploy my software on a server with better hardware and then I have to reestimate my connection pool sizes?!

Comment: You can externalize these 'tuning' variables to an environment specific configuration file and read them in when your program starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 4.2 one can use a BackoffManager in order to dynamically  adjusts the size of an available connection pool based on feedback from using persistent connections.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AIMDBackoffManager.html